# Does UV light from fluorescent neon tubes affect resin prints?

Tags: print-quality, resin

I recently replaced one of the fluorescent neon tubes in my garage and noticed a sticker on the packageing saying the neon tube in question was only giving off low amounts of UV light. I wasn't even sure, fluorescent neon tubes were emitting UV light at all, but now I am wondering if the light coming off these lamps affect the quality of the resin 3D prints?

Comment: It might but, as I understand it, the wavelength of the UV light is what causes the resin to cure. If the wavelength of the UV light and the resin is the same and if the intensity of the UV light is high enough to affect the resin, then you will have a problem. (As I am not that familiar with resin printing, I am posting this as a comment. Maybe someone more knowledgeable can confirm/correct my statements.)